# How to identify unique items in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-mining

I have dataset containing numbers (for itemset mining). The dataset is as follow:

[image: Dataset.csv]

How can I identify unique items from this?

My current attempt is as follows:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', sep='\t')
pd.unique(dataset)
```

But I'm getting the error: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3000,1) into shape (3000)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.unique` expects **1d array-like** input so you can try `pd.unique(dataset.values.ravel())`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. It seems that each row is a list with variable length. Let me guess.

If you actually want the dataframe to have all the lists in one column, instead of a bunch of columns with NaN everywhere, try this after read_csv:

```
dataset.apply(lambda x: list(x), axis=1)
```

If you want unique rows, the easiest way is:

```
uniques = dataset.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```

If you want unique values of a particular column:

```
dataset["column name"].unique()
```

will return a numpy array of unique values.